# Как получить доступ к label при input:focus?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Каким образом получить доступ к label при фокусе в input?

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input, label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  height: 35px;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="username" />
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper"> 
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="password" />
</div>
```

**NB**: 
Не подходят варианты с перестановкой лейбла и инпута. Можем как угодно править css, но не html.

**UPD:** [Пример](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy) механики которую хочу добиться см тут в разделе "Label text", картинка с подписью (что как бы намекает, но все-равно интересно же):

> Don’t. Label text shouldn’t take up multiple lines.

Comment: А вам зачем? Подозреваю, что нужно скрывать `label` при фокусе на `input`. Если да, то для этих целей лучше использовать `placeholder`. Пример: `<input type="text" placeholder="Password" />`. В противном случае только `JS`

Comment: Нет, необходимо "поднимать" label над input, при этом вариант с вытаскиванием label из DOM не подходит как и вариант с :after/:befor.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nikhil8krishnan/pen/ALLLkv?editors=1010

Comment: на чистом css Вы не сможете получить доступ к элементу, идущему ПЕРЕД - только ПОСЛЕ. так что либо js (jquery), либо меняйте label и input местами

Comment: Мне необходимо чтобы лейбл не наезжал на инпут вне зависимости от того на сколько он строк. Возможно есть какой-то вариант с заменой лейбла и инпута местами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без js (на чистом css), но с перестановкой элементов местами:

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input, label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  height: 35px;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  transition: .5s;
}

#username:focus ~ label[for="username"],
#username:valid ~ label[for="username"],
#password:focus ~ label[for="password"],
#password:valid ~ label[for="password"]{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="textbox" id="username" required />
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper"> 
  <input type="textbox" id="password" required />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
</div>
```

Comment: всё дело в том, что `label` надо поднимать не только и не столько при фокусе, сколько при наличии текста в `input`-е. Можно, конечно использовать хаки типа `:placeholder-shown`, но поддержа пока не полная. Так что без js не обойтись.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, в вопросе речь именно про фокус, а не про наличие или отсутствие текста: "Как получить доступ к label при input:focus?"

Comment: это да. Но нам то с вами понятно для чего это делается.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, а, я понял, о чём Вы, да. Но и на чистом html-css можно решить этот вопрос: достаточно сделать поле обязательным и проверять на заполненность с помощью :valid. я добавил это в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без перестановки

```js
function toggleInput(){
  if(this.value){
    $(this).parent('.input-wrapper').addClass('active');
  }else{
     $(this).parent('.input-wrapper').removeClass('active');
  }
}
$('.input-wrapper input').each(toggleInput); //на случай предустановленного значения
$('.input-wrapper input').on('input',toggleInput);//при изменении
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position:relative;
}

input, label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  height: 35px;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  position:absolute;
  transition:all .2s ease;
  bottom:.6em;
  pointer-events:none;
  white-space:nowrap;/*чтобы был всегда в одну строку*/
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.input-wrapper.active label{
  bottom:100%;
  font-size:75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" value="Вахтанг" />
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper"> 
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" />
</div>
```

Вариант на `css` (с перестановкой): нужно задать `input`-ам `placeholder` из пробела и проверять наличие значения при помощи псевдокласса `:placeholder-shown` и `:not`. Такой способ не поддерживается в IE.

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position:relative;
}

input, label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  height: 35px;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  position:absolute;
  transition:all .2s ease;
  bottom:.6em;
  pointer-events:none;
  white-space:nowrap;/*чтобы был всегда в одну строку*/
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.input-wrapper input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
.input-wrapper input:focus+label{
  bottom:100%;
  font-size:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">  
  <input type="text" id="username" value="Вахтанг" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>  
</div>
```